# How to post JSON Data through MQTT on Bluemix using C#?

Tags: c#, ibm-cloud, mqtt

I am new to Bluemix MQTT need to post JSON data at regular interval using MQTT Protocol to Bluemix in C#. I can't find any reference documents.

Are there any reference documents that I can look at related to .net framework?

Comment: Do you plan to use the Watson IoT platform for storing your data in the cloud?

Comment: yes  ValerieLampkin i want to post my sensor data on bluemix using mqtt protocol

Answer (score 1):

Here is info about c# [application development](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/libraries/c_sharp.html) for Watson IoT Platform and for [devices](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/libraries/c_sharp.html)

For example: publishing from device -

```
deviceClient.connect();
deviceClient.publishEvent("event", "json", "{temp:23}");
```

Also, see MQTT application development for [applications](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/mqtt.html) and [devices.](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/mqtt.html)

Here are samples in [GitHub](https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-csharp?cm_mc_uid=41893914391914121143444&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1468852145) for Watson IoT c# applications.